# Different behavior of base R gsub and stringr::str_replace_all?

Tags: r, regex, stringr, string-substitution

I would expect `gsub` and `stringr::str_replace_all` to return the same result in the following, but only `gsub` returns the intended result. I am developing a lesson to demonstrate `str_replace_all` so I would like to know why it returns a different result here.

```
txt <- ".72   2.51\n2015**   2.45   2.30   2.00   1.44   1.20   1.54   1.84   1.56   1.94   1.47   0.86   1.01\n2016**   1.53   1.75   2.40   2.62   2.35   2.03   1.25   0.52   0.45   0.56   1.88   1.17\n2017**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n2018**   0.70   0"

gsub(".*2017|2018.*", "", txt)

stringr::str_replace_all(txt, ".*2017|2018.*", "")
```

`gsub` returns the intended output (everything before and including `2017`, and after and including `2018`, has been removed).

**output of gsub (intended)**

```
[1] "**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"
```

However `str_replace_all` only replaces the `2017` and `2018` but leaves the rest, even though the same `pattern` is used for both.

**output of str_replace_all (not intended)**

```
[1] ".72   2.51\n2015**   2.45   2.30   2.00   1.44   1.20   1.54   1.84   1.56   1.94   1.47   0.86   1.01\n2016**   1.53   1.75   2.40   2.62   2.35   2.03   1.25   0.52   0.45   0.56   1.88   1.17\n**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"
```

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base R relies on two regex libraries.
As default R uses [TRE](http://laurikari.net/tre/documentation/regex-syntax/).
We can specify `perl = TRUE` to use PCRE (perl like regular expressions).
The {stringr} package uses ICU (Java like regular expressions).

In your case the problem is that the dot `.` doesn’t match line breaks in PCRE and ICU, while it does match line breaks in TRE:

```r
library(stringr)

txt <- ".72   2.51\n2015**   2.45   2.30   2.00   1.44   1.20   1.54   1.84   1.56   1.94   1.47   0.86   1.01\n2016**   1.53   1.75   2.40   2.62   2.35   2.03   1.25   0.52   0.45   0.56   1.88   1.17\n2017**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n2018**   0.70   0"

(base_tre <- gsub(".*2017|2018.*", "", txt))
#> [1] "**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"
(base_perl <- gsub(".*2017|2018.*", "", txt, perl = TRUE))
#> [1] ".72   2.51\n2015**   2.45   2.30   2.00   1.44   1.20   1.54   1.84   1.56   1.94   1.47   0.86   1.01\n2016**   1.53   1.75   2.40   2.62   2.35   2.03   1.25   0.52   0.45   0.56   1.88   1.17\n**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"
(string_r <- str_replace_all(txt, ".*2017|2018.*", ""))
#> [1] ".72   2.51\n2015**   2.45   2.30   2.00   1.44   1.20   1.54   1.84   1.56   1.94   1.47   0.86   1.01\n2016**   1.53   1.75   2.40   2.62   2.35   2.03   1.25   0.52   0.45   0.56   1.88   1.17\n**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"

identical(base_perl, string_r)
#> [1] TRUE
```

We can use [modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html)
to change the behavior of PCRE and ICU regex so that line breaks are matched
by `.`. This will produce the same output as with base R TRE:

```r
(base_perl <- gsub("(?s).*2017|2018(?s).*", "", txt, perl = TRUE))
#> [1] "**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"

(string_r <- str_replace_all(txt, "(?s).*2017|2018(?s).*", ""))
#> [1] "**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50\n"

identical(base_perl, string_r)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Finally, unlike TRE, PCRE and ICU allow us to use look arounds which are also
an option to solve the problem

```r
str_match(txt, "(?<=2017).*.(?=\\n2018)")
#>      [,1]                                                                                    
#> [1,] "**   0.77   0.70   0.74   1.12   0.88   0.79   0.10   0.09   0.32   0.05   0.15   0.50"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's helpful but how do I modify the `str_replace_all` function to get the default result of `gsub` with `perl = FALSE`?

Comment: You could use look aheads to match your expression (instead of replacing it with `""`).